# Значение Ip-адреса в столбце mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть лог-файл в формате .txt В нем среди прочего содержится столбец "IP" с находящимися ip-адресами в виде "192.168.1.1". Нужно добавить данный столбец в таблицу со значением столбца unsigned int (использую dbforge), но программа ругается из-за наличия точек. INET_ATOP в программе при импорте информации не предусмотрен. Как быть?

Comment: если предлагаемый инструмент не справляется с поставленной задачей, вероятно, стоит попробовать другой инструмент. в данном случае — «самую обычную» программу *mysql*. а данные для неё подготавливать подсобными утилитами командной строки (сложность или простота такого подхода зависит, конечно, от используемой операционный системы).

Comment: другой вариант: сначала заменить в исходном файле *ip-адрес* на его *integer-представление*, а потом уже импортировать получившийся файл.

Comment: изменть запрос так, что-бы он использовал эту функцию - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton - возможно?

Comment: ungigned int = (192 << 24) + (168 << 16) + (1 << 8) + (1)